# Получить соседние элементы с учетом сортировки Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть таблица users, в ней поля name, last_name.

Задача:

1. Отсортировать список по полям last_name и name
2. Получить соседние элементы (предыдущий/следующий)
3. Если идет выборка от крайнего элемента у которого нет следующего элемента, то подставится первый, т.о. необходимо зациклить переключение

Как получить элемент, не учитывая сортировку, понятно:

```
$prev = User::where('id', '<', $currentUserId)->latest('id')->first();
$next = User::where('id', '>', $currentUserId)->oldest('id')->first();
```

Подскажите, как сделать с сортировкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогу пришел к следующему решению:

1. Сперва получаем коллекцию пользователей

```php
$listUsers = User::query()->whereActive(true)
            ->orderBy('last_name')
            ->pluck('id');
```

2. Подсчитываем количество найденных пользователей и достаем индекс пользователя от которого будем искать соседей.

```php
$countUsers = $listUsers->count();
$indexCurrentUser = $listUsers->search($this->id);
```

3. И последнее, достаем этих соседей

```php
return [
    'prev' => $indexCurrentUser === 0 ? $listUsers[$countUsers - 1] : $listUsers[$indexCurrentUser - 1],
    'next' => $indexCurrentUser + 1 === $countUsers ? $listUsers[0] : $listUsers[$indexCurrentUser + 1],
];
```